# I have a proglem with nhibernate fluent with C# + MVC. It doesn't make id unique

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a proglem with nhibernate fluent with C# + MVC.
It doesn't make id unique.

I run my application.
Add post. Its id is 1.

I stopped my app. Then I run it again and if i create new record it is generated id 1 for another post and write it over previous.

```
public class Post
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    ...     
}
```

Mapping

```
public class PostMap : ClassMap<Post>
{
    public PostMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);            

        Map(x => x.Title)
            .Length(500);
        ...
```

Helper

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)

                InitializeSessionFactory();
            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }


    private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
                    .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("DefaultConnection")))                
                    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Post>())
                    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                                            .Create(true, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();            
    }


    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Blog repository

```
public class  BlogRepository 
{ 
   public int AddPost(Post post)
    {
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(post);
                tran.Commit();
                return post.Id;
            }
        }
    }
```

code snippet:

```
var _blogRepository = new BlogRepository(); 
var post = new Post(); 
post.Title = "Form den3"; 
post.PostedOn = DateTime.Now; 
post.Modified = DateTime.Now; 
var postID = _blogRepository.AddPost(post);
```

Comment: Any code you can share?

Comment: It's been a while since I used nHibernate, but don't you have to specify that it's a db generated identity column in the class map? So `Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity()`

Comment: I tried Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity() but situation still the same (

Answer (score 1):

Mapping as is, should be ok and should use `Identity` *(the default)*. And this line:

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity()
```

should assure, that the identity is used. But as said in comments, it is not working either.

The most suspected to me is this piece of code:

```
new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true))
```

This in fact DROPS the tables and recreate them. Which could end up in "regenerated" id == 1.

So, try to not use that, if really needed use just `.Update()`